# Scheduling a MySQL event

Tags: mysql

I have something like below:

```
CREATE EVENT evtConvertExpiredPointsToWinChance
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 QUARTER
STARTS '2016-01-02 00:00:00'
DO CALL storedProcedureName;
```

I am not sure why it does not work. I tried setting my system clock to `2016-01-01 23:59:30` and wait for it to past the target time, but I dont think it ran. If I do a `CALL storedProcedureName` manually it worked.

It seems if I do a small interval (every 5 second) it works ... but wonder why? What does QUATER mean? Does it mean the 1st event will run 1 quarter after my start date?

```
mysql> select * from mysql.event\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  db: meclub
                name: evtConvertExpiredPointsToWinChance
                body: CALL convertExpiredPointsToWinChances
             definer: root@localhost
          execute_at: NULL
      interval_value: 1
      interval_field: MONTH
             created: 2016-01-01 00:04:33
            modified: 2016-01-01 00:04:33
       last_executed: NULL
              starts: 2013-12-31 16:00:00
                ends: NULL
              status: ENABLED
       on_completion: DROP
            sql_mode: NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
             comment: 
          originator: 0
           time_zone: SYSTEM
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
        db_collation: utf8_general_ci
           body_utf8: CALL convertExpiredPointsToWinChances
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I notice the starts is `2013-12-31 16:00:00` so does it mean it will start every month @4PM? So it does not take the time I passed it? In the above example I tried `1 MONTH` as interval

**UPDATE**

Maybe me messing with system time is messing up MySQL too?

```
mysql> select * from mysql.event\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             created: 2015-12-31 16:43:54
            modified: 2015-12-31 16:43:54
       last_executed: 2015-12-31 08:47:00
              starts: 2013-12-31 16:00:00
```

Wonder how can last_executed be earlier than creation time ...

**UPDATE2**

Wonder if this is a timezone thing? When I pass in a datetime string to `STARTS` what timezone is it for? UTC? I am currently UTC+8

Comment: Did you start the scheduler using `SET GLOBAL EVENT_SCHEDULER=ON`?

Comment: @MatsKindahl, yes, events work when I set them to a small interval for example 5 second. For larger intervals, it might be that I need to set it to the right time for it to be triggered? For example, in my example, if I set the start time to be `00:00:00` I'd expect when I set my system clock to `23:59:50` and let it pass `00:00`, the event should run?